# Sorting of a list with different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list of disordered numbers. They are collected in different lists. I mean

```
list = {
   {1, 13, 5},
   {3, 94, 85, 21, 7, 5, 6},
   {2, 5, 9, 88, 4, 15, 36, 4, 8},
   {5, 3, 12, 3},
   {0, 1, 5, 66, 4, 8},
   {5, 8, 7, 4, 6, 2, 55, 98, 4, 65, 4}
   };
```

I want to have the list in an ordered form but when I use `Sortby[list, Last]` or `Sort[list]` nothing happens. How can I sort the list to have the results as

```
{  {1, 5, 13},
   {3, 5, 6, 7, 21, 85, 94},
   {2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 36, 88},
   {3, 3, 5, 12},
   {0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 66},
   {2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 55, 65, 98}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Map[Sort, list]
(*{{1, 5, 13}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 21, 85, 94}, {2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 36, 
88}, {3, 3, 5, 12}, {0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 66}, {2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
55, 65, 98}}*)
```

Comment: And there is also the shortcut for mapping: Sort /@ list